# Messages in iCloud Won’t Delete from macOS

Tags: macos, icloud, messages, messages-in-icloud

If I delete a message from Messages on my iPhone or iPad connected to **Messages in iCloud**, it gets deleted from all my other devices. However if I do the same from my Mac also connected to **Messages in iCloud**, the message/conversation only gets deleted from the Mac.

How do I make message deletion work correctly from a Mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of macOS 10.13.5 High Sierra, it appears you need to *disable* **Save history when conversations are closed** for message deletion to function as advertised over iCloud.

To do this, open **Messages**, then from the menu bar navigate to Messages → Preferences… → General. *Uncheck* this box:

[image: Save history when conversations are closed]

It’s unclear whether this is the expected behavior, but it sure looks like a bug.